# A test suite of large systems of nonlinear equations

Tags: nonlinear-equations, reference-request

I am looking for a kind of modern test set of large nonlinear problems. The only option I managed to find so far is rather dated: http://folk.uib.no/ssu029/Pdf_file/Testproblems/testprobRheinboldt03.pdf

Comment: What is the final application? Do you wish to test a numerical solver your are designing? Benchmark it? Are you looking for specific non-linear equatgions (PDE or ODE? etc.)?

Comment: @BlaisB, yes, I want to test a method similar to jacobian-free Newton-Krylov. Any kind of application can come in handy.